# Как сделать, чтобы ключи интерфейса соответствовали списку ключей?

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Есть перечисленные ключи:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
```

Они могут быть взяты например из другого интерфейса через `keyof`, или могут быть просто перечислены как тут.

И есть другие интерфейсы, которые должны иметь именно эти ключи, и никакие больше:

```
interface X {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: MyAnytype;
    z: number; // должна быть ошибка - лишний ключ "z"
}

interface Y { // должна быть ошибка - не найден ключ "b"
    a: 'some-type';
    c: Function;
}
```

В значениях могут быть любые типы, которые я перечислю руками, не автоматические как в `{[key in Keys]: number}`. Типы значений не должны никак расширяться или подменяться более общими или другими.

Как добиться такой проверки ключей у типов?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал такой костыль-проверяльщик:

```
type Check = {
    [key in Keys]: X[key];
} | {
    [key in keyof X]: { [innerKey in Keys]: any }[key];
}
```

Он проверяет ключи в "обе стороны". При несоответствии списка интерфейсу, или интерфейса списку, подсвечивается ошибкой какая-то из строк данного проверяльщика. Годится, чтобы не прошло компиляцию.

Но нужно нормальное решение.